# Breaking down your RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Some of my Rspec tests have gotten really really big (2000-5000 lines). I am just wondering if anyone has ever tried breaking these tests down into multiple files that meet the following conditions:

- There is a systematic way of naming and placing your test (e.g. methods A-L gos to user_spec1.rb).
- You can run a single file that will actually run the other tests inside other files.
- You can still run a specific context within a file
- and, good to have, RubyMine can run a specific test (and all tests) just fine.

For now, I have been successful in doing

```
#user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../user_spec1.rb", __FILE__)
include UserSpec

#user_spec1.rb
module UserSpec do
  describe User do
    ..
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered tagging them instead?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite sure what you mean by tagging

Comment: You can tag individual specs and run them together.

Comment: oh, I see.. well how does that help in terms of breaking down the number of tests in 1 file though? The idea behind this is I guess to help developers in terms organizing their test. There should be a systematic way to find test and to place new tests. New developers should be able to easily find/place tests for existing/new methods.

Comment: ... Because you can tag specs in different files with the same tag. How you break down tests is arbitrary (although doing it alphabetically is arbitrary; by functionality would make a lot more sense).

Comment: well suppose this spec is for a model. what do you think about breaking down the file by each methods purpose (callback, private, public, association, validations). Do you see any obvious drawback from this?

Comment: Totally depends. Visibility is also essentially arbitrary. Validations makes sense.

Comment: this wont help much especially when you have a lot of instance public methods.

Comment: Why not? Just saying something won't help is useless. Tagging is a pretty common way to group disparate specs (or anything else).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your specs are getting too big, it's likely that your model is too big as well -- since you used "UserSpec" here, you could say your user class is a "[God class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)". That is, it does too much.

So, I would break this up into much smaller classes, each of which have one single responsibility. Then, test these classes in isolation.

What you may find is that your User class knows how to execute most logic in your system -- this is an easy trap to fall into, but can be avoided if you put your logic in a class that takes a user as an argument... Also if you steadfastly follow the law of demeter (where your user class could only touch 1 level below it, but not two).

Further Reading: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/055-issue-23-solid-design.html

Comment: I am not able to access this link